# Tensorflow Dataset in predict() method throws error

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am currently trying to use a Tensorflow dataset as input to the predict() function of a tensorflow model. For some reason, I always get an error, details are below.

I have the following generator:

```
def create_dataset(Q, unary_potentials, features_1, features_2, features_3, kernel_size, depth_image):
    height, width, _ = np.shape(unary_potentials)
    Q = np.pad(Q, [[kernel_size, kernel_size], [kernel_size, kernel_size], [0, 0]])
    unary_potentials = np.pad(unary_potentials, [[kernel_size, kernel_size], [kernel_size, kernel_size], [0, 0]])
    features_1 = np.pad(features_1, [[kernel_size, kernel_size], [kernel_size, kernel_size], [0, 0]])
    features_2 = np.pad(features_2, [[kernel_size, kernel_size], [kernel_size, kernel_size], [0, 0]])
    features_3 = np.pad(features_3, [[kernel_size, kernel_size], [kernel_size, kernel_size], [0, 0]])
    for y in range(kernel_size, height+kernel_size):
        print(f"y: {y}")
        Q_rows = Q[y-kernel_size:y+kernel_size+1]
        unary_rows = unary_potentials[y-kernel_size:y+kernel_size+1]
        f_1_rows = features_1[y-kernel_size:y+kernel_size+1]
        f_2_rows = features_2[y-kernel_size:y+kernel_size+1]
        f_3_rows = features_3[y-kernel_size:y+kernel_size+1]
        for x in range(kernel_size, width+kernel_size):
            if depth_image[y-kernel_size][x-kernel_size] > 0.0001:
                yield  f_1_rows[kernel_size][x], f_2_rows[kernel_size][x], f_3_rows[kernel_size][x],\
                       unary_rows[:, x-kernel_size:x+kernel_size+1], Q_rows[:, x-kernel_size:x+kernel_size+1],\
                       f_1_rows[:, x-kernel_size:x+kernel_size+1], f_2_rows[:, x-kernel_size:x+kernel_size+1],\
                       f_3_rows[:, x-kernel_size:x+kernel_size+1]
```

I am returning some numpy arrays from the generator.
Then I build the dataset like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(create_dataset,
                                             output_shapes=((3,), (6,), (5,), (kernel_size*2+1, kernel_size*2+1, number_of_surfaces),
                                                            (kernel_size*2+1, kernel_size*2+1, number_of_surfaces),
                                                            (kernel_size*2+1, kernel_size*2+1, 3),
                                                            (kernel_size*2+1, kernel_size*2+1, 6),
                                                            (kernel_size*2+1, kernel_size*2+1, 5)),
                                             output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32),
                                             args=(initial_Q, unary_potentials, *features, kernel_size, depth_image)).batch(batch_size)
```

If I now call

```
Q = MFI_NN.predict(dataset)
```

where MFI_NN is my model, I just get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/marc/Desktop/MA/Code/find_planes_MS.py", line 496, in <module>
    test_model_on_image_2(test_indices[0])
  File "C:/Users/marc/Desktop/MA/Code/find_planes_MS.py", line 199, in test_model_on_image_2
    Q = MFI_NN.predict(x=dataset)
  File "C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1629, in predict
    tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 725, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3196, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1478 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1468 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1461 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1433 predict_step
        x, _, _ = data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(data)
    C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py:1454 unpack_x_y_sample_weight
        raise ValueError(error_msg)

    ValueError: Data is expected to be in format `x`, `(x,)`, `(x, y)`, or `(x, y, sample_weight)`, found: (<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, 6) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None, 5) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:3' shape=(None, 21, 21, 49) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:4' shape=(None, 21, 21, 49) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:5' shape=(None, 21, 21, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:6' shape=(None, 21, 21, 6) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:7' shape=(None, 21, 21, 5) dtype=float32>)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

The output of the generator itself is definitely correct though, since the following works fine:

```
for x in dataset:
    Q = MFI_NN.predict(x)
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious here, it would be great if someone could tell me what it is.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [tf.keras.Model.predict()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) method:

> x  Input samples. It could be:

> > A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs).
> > A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).
> > A tf.data dataset.
> > A generator or keras.utils.Sequence instance. A more detailed description of unpacking behavior for iterator types (Dataset, generator, Sequence) is given in the Unpacking behavior for iterator-like inputs section of Model.fit.

So, I would reccomend you to pass the `dataset` directly in to `MFI_NN.predict()`, like:

```
    Q = MFI_NN.predict(dataset)  # dataset is a tf.data dataset.
```

or if you need `for` loop for some other reason:

```
for x in dataset:
    Q = MFI_NN.predict([x])  # [x] is a list of tensors.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately there was an error in my question, because I actually did use Q = MFI_NN.predict(dataset) (I just copied the wrong thing into the question). This case is exactly the case where the error occurs.

Comment: It will be helpful to edit your question then, in order to be easier to understand your problem. Does passing the dataset output from the for loop as a list to predict method solved your problem?

Comment: If I do it as a for loop like I showed it in my question, it works. But obviously I would rather use the normal predict() method on the dataset. The reason why I do not just call predict() on the complete dataset as a list is that it is just too big, so using the generator is necessary.
For now I just settled with the for loop, even though it is less elegant and probably less efficient.